# Как горизонтально выровнять надписи относительно "Бургера" на мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-grid

Есть вот такой сайт:
https://client.evroflag.by/purl2/index.php?c=72764&p=3399072&e=13

На его мобильной версии, есть 2 мобильных меню. Рядом с которыми их названия.

Но я не могу понять, как их поровнять относительно бургеров, чтобы всё работало.

Посмотрите как сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста советом, как с помощью HTML/CSS, поровнять эти 2 бургера с их названиями.

Большое Спасибо, тем кто поможет.

P.S. Пробовал с помощью флекса, но тогда начинает криво открываться меню.

Comment: Покажите ваши текущие стили для бургера(отредактируйте вопрос)

Comment: c помощью флекса и нужно делать, но только флекс, прицепить только на div в котом находится лишь бургер и текст возле него…

Comment: @SergBakay я делал так, но ломается меню, которое ломается при нажатии на бургер.